# I have issues installing wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

Can anyone help me out with installing wxpython
[Please check attached wxpython installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xbTH.png)

Answer (score 0):

the log is telling what you have to do. Have you try install Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0? No?

Your python version is 2.7?

If yes, so download and install Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 from the following link:

https://web.archive.org/web/20190720195601/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266